# why jenkins job is not failing - even if npm script fails in stage?

Tags: jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, npm-install, npm-scripts

I have following Jenkinsfile:

```
        stage('build mod') {
            steps {
                dir("cli") {
                    script {
                        try {
                            sh('node index.js -m shell -h project -p max4 -i local')
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                            throw e
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The script fails:

```
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /home/jenkins/.npm/_logs/-debug.log
```

But the stage passes with green... Why try-catch did not work in this case?

Comment: Does that command definitely exit non-zero overall?

Comment: If you want to stop your build you can try to use `error(text)` but I think the exception should work as well. Can you provide more information?

Comment: script returns 0... case solved... I need to make this script to fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost  you need to understand that even though the code inside of the script failed, the shell function that jenkinsfile had called was successful. That's wht jenkinsfile couldn't catch the error as the script returned 0. So you need to write a code that will catch the return value of the code executing inside that of the script. Something similar to

```
result = sh (
    script: "node index.js -m shell -h project -p max4 -i local",
    returnStatus: true
)
if (result != 0) {
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    break
}
```

Here "break" is very important as we don't want other stages to get executed once build has failed.